# How can i fix this error by rending in shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Hi everyone i want to create a shiny App to plot the histogram .  code ist like this:

```
    tabPanel("Plot with 2 Facets",
                          #titlePanel("Statistik SS2022"),
                          
                          # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              sliderInput("bins",
                                          "Number of bins:",
                                          min = 1,
                                          max = 50,
                                          value = 30),
                              selectInput("factor1", label = h3("Select a factor"), 
                                          choices = c("Age" , "SibSp", 
                                                      "Parch"), 
                                          selected = "Age"),
                              selectInput("factor2", label = h3("Select a facet"), 
                                          choices = c("Sex" , "Pclass", "Embarked", "SibSp", 
                                                      "Parch", "Age"), 
                                          selected = "Sex"),
                              selectInput("factor3", label = h3("Select a facet"), 
                                          choices = c( "Pclass", "Embarked", "SibSp", 
                                                      "Parch"), 
                                          selected = "Pclass")
                              
                            ),
                            mainPanel(
                              #plotOutput("distPlot"),
                              
                              # plotOutput("Barplot"),
                              
                              plotOutput("Histogramm")
                              
                            )
                          )
                 
                 
                 
                 
                 )
```

The renderPlot is like this:

```
    
        ggplot(titanic_data, aes(x = titanic_data[[input$factor1]], fill = Survived)) +
              
              facet_wrap(titanic_data[[input$factor2]] ~ titanic_data[[input$factor3]]) +
              theme_bw()+
              #geom_bar(aes(y =(..count..)/sum(..count..)))+
              geom_histogram(binwidth = 10) +
              
              labs(y = "Relative Sequences",
                   x = "Survived",
                   title = paste('Titanic Survival Rates by',input$factor1 ,'and' ,input$factor2,' , ',input$factor3))
```

i got this error:

```
StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete.Perhaps you want stat="count"?
```

before i use this code to render the histogramm in R :

```
    
        ggplot(titanic_data, aes(x = Age, fill = Survived)) +
          theme_bw() +
          facet_wrap(Sex ~ Pclass) +
          geom_histogram(binwidth = 5) +
          labs(y = "Count",
               x = "Survived",
               title = "Titanic Survival Rates by Age, Pclass and Sex")
```

and i got like this :

[image: histogramm]

so i change to use geom_bar

```
    output$Histogramm <- renderPlot({
          
          if (input$factor1 == "Sex") {
            xlabel <- "Sex"}
          else if (input$factor1 == "Pclass") {
            xlabel <- "Pclass"}
          else if (input$factor1 == "Age") {
            xlabel <- "Age"}
          else if (input$factor1 == "Embarked") {
            xlabel <- "Embarked"}
          else if (input$factor1 == "SibSp") {
            xlabel <- "SibSp"}
          else if (input$factor1 == "Parch") {
            xlabel <- "Parch"}
          else if (input$factor1 == "Age") {
            xlabel <- "Age"}
          
          
          
          
          
          ggplot(titanic_data, aes(x = titanic_data[[input$factor1]], fill = Survived)) +
            
            facet_wrap(titanic_data[[input$factor2]] ~ titanic_data[[input$factor3]]) +
            theme_bw()+
            geom_bar(aes(y =(..count..)/sum(..count..)))+
            labs(y = "Relative Sequences",
                 x = xlabel,
                 title = paste('Titanic Survival Rates by',input$factor1 ,'and' ,input$factor2,' , ',input$factor3)) 
          
          
          
        })
```

and i got this plot:

[image: Barplot]

it did not render the Age like i want .
Could someone help me.

before i use this code :

```
    ggplot(titanic_data, aes(x = Age, y =(..count..)/sum(..count..),fill = Survived)) +
          
          theme_bw() +
          facet_wrap(Sex ~ Pclass) +
          geom_bar() +
          labs(y = "relative sequences",
               x = "Survived",
               title = "Titanic Survival Rates by Age, Pclass and Sex")
```

i got kind of this plot:
[image: barplot i want]

Could someone help me. Thank you so much!!

Update:

the data is like this:

```
    PassengerId Survived Pclass Name          Sex     Age SibSp Parch Ticket  Fare Cabin
            <dbl> <fct>    <fct>  <chr>         <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
    1           1 0        3      Braund, Mr. … male     22     1     0 A/5 2…  7.25 NA   
    2           2 1        1      Cumings, Mrs… fema…    38     1     0 PC 17… 71.3  C85  
    3           3 1        3      Heikkinen, M… fema…    26     0     0 STON/…  7.92 NA   
    4           4 1        1      Futrelle, Mr… fema…    35     1     0 113803 53.1  C123 
    5           5 0        3      Allen, Mr. W… male     35     0     0 373450  8.05 NA   
    6           6 0        3      Moran, Mr. J… male     NA     0     0 330877  8.46 NA
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and a full [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), if you want someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ggplot(titanic_data, aes(x = .data[[input$factor1]], fill = Survived)) +
      facet_wrap(titanic_data[[input$factor2]] ~ titanic_data[[input$factor3]]) +
      theme_bw()+
      geom_histogram(stat="count",binwidth = 10) +
      labs(y = "Relative Sequences",
           x = "Survived",
           title = paste('Titanic Survival Rates by',input$factor1 ,'and' ,input$factor2,' , ',input$factor3))
```

Comment: hi i tried but i still doesn't work. thank you